# How to add OnClickListener in Andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

Can anyone help me out? I'm trying to implement an OnClickListener that let's my code go to the main game. I don't know how to do the coding of the clicklistener in AndEngine.

I'm stuck at the part where I am able to output the images only, not as clickable images.

UPDATE:
The Play image/button doesn't seem to function even after adding this code to it. Can anyone help?

Added Code for GameActivity:

```
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
         if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        // you can implement your action
             sceneManager.loadGameResources();
                sceneManager.createGameScene();
          sceneManager.setCurrentScene(AllScenes.GAME);
}

     return onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);

 }
```

Added Code for SceneManager:

```
public Scene createMenuScene()
{
    menuScene = new Scene();
    menuScene.setBackground(new Background (0,0,0));

    Sprite icon = new Sprite (0,0, menuTR, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    icon.setPosition((camera.getWidth() - icon.getWidth()) /2, (camera.getHeight() - icon.getHeight()) /2 );
    menuScene.attachChild(icon);


    Sprite play = new Sprite (180, 350, playTR, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    this.menuScene.attachChild(play);
    this.menuScene.registerTouchArea(play);

    Sprite quit = new Sprite (500,350, quitTR, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    menuScene.attachChild(quit);
    return menuScene;
}
public Scene createGameScene()
{

return gameScene;   
}
```

Here's the code for my GameActivity:

```
public class GameActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

Scene scene;
protected static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
protected static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
BitmapTextureAtlas playerTexture;
ITextureRegion playerTextureRegion;
PhysicsWorld physicsWorld;


SceneManager sceneManager;
Camera mCamera;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

mCamera = new Camera (0,0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy (CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
return options;
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception {


    sceneManager = new SceneManager(this, mEngine, mCamera);
    sceneManager.loadSplashResources();

    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}


@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {

    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(sceneManager.createSplashScene());

}

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {

    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(3f, new ITimerCallback(){


        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler)
        {
            mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            sceneManager.loadMenuResources();
            sceneManager.createMenuScene();
            sceneManager.setCurrentScene(AllScenes.MENU);
        }
    }));
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}



}
```

and here's my code for the SceneManager:

```
public class SceneManager {
private AllScenes currentScene;
private BaseGameActivity activity; // Name of other activity GameActivity
private Engine engine;
private Camera camera;
private BitmapTextureAtlas splashTA, menuTA, playTA, quitTA;
private ITextureRegion splashTR, menuTR, playTR , quitTR;
private Scene splashScene, gameScene, menuScene;

public enum AllScenes 
{
    SPLASH, MENU, GAME
}

public SceneManager(BaseGameActivity act, Engine eng, Camera cam)
{
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.activity = act;
    this.engine = eng;
    this.camera = cam;
} 
public AllScenes getCurrentScene()
{
    return currentScene;
}

public void setCurrentScene(AllScenes currentScene)
{
    this.currentScene = currentScene;


    switch(currentScene)
    {
    case SPLASH:

        break;
    case MENU:
        engine.setScene(menuScene);

        break;
    case GAME:

        engine.setScene(gameScene);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void loadSplashResources() 
{
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    splashTA = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256);
    splashTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(splashTA, this.activity, "splash.png", 0,0);
    splashTA.load();
}

public void loadGameResources()
{

}

public void loadMenuResources()
{
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    menuTA = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.activity.getTextureManager(), 800, 480);
    menuTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(menuTA, this.activity, "menu.png", 0, 0);
    menuTA.load();

    playTA = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.activity.getTextureManager(), 140, 42);
    playTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(playTA, this.activity, "play.png", 0, 0);
    playTA.load();

    quitTA = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.activity.getTextureManager(), 140, 42);
    quitTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(quitTA, this.activity, "quit.png", 0, 0);
    quitTA.load();
}

public Scene createSplashScene()
{
    splashScene = new Scene();
    splashScene.setBackground(new Background(233,242,237));

    Sprite icon = new Sprite(0,0, splashTR, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    icon.setPosition((camera.getWidth()-icon.getWidth())/2, (camera.getHeight() - icon.getHeight()) /2 );
    splashScene.attachChild(icon);
    return splashScene;
}

public Scene createMenuScene()
{
    menuScene = new Scene();
    menuScene.setBackground(new Background (0,0,0));

    Sprite icon = new Sprite (0,0, menuTR, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    icon.setPosition((camera.getWidth() - icon.getWidth()) /2, (camera.getHeight() - icon.getHeight()) /2 );
    menuScene.attachChild(icon);


    Sprite play = new Sprite (0,0, playTR, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    play.setPosition(180, 350 );
    menuScene.attachChild(play);

    Sprite quit = new Sprite (0,0, quitTR, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    quit.setPosition(500, 350);
    menuScene.attachChild(quit);
    return menuScene;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Scene createMenuScene()
{
    menuScene = new Scene();
    menuScene.setBackground(new Background (0,0,0));

    Sprite icon = new Sprite (0,0, menuTR, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    icon.setPosition((camera.getWidth() - icon.getWidth()) /2, (camera.getHeight() - icon.getHeight()) /2 );
    menuScene.attachChild(icon);


  Sprite playSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, playTR, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                            float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                           // you can implement your action
                                      sceneManager.setCurrentScene(AllScenes.GAME);
}

                        return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
                    }
                };

                menuScene.registerTouchArea(playSprite);
              play.setPosition(180, 350 );
               menuScene.attachChild(playSprite);




  Sprite quitSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, quitTR, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                            float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                           // you can implement your action to quit

}

                        return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
                    }
                };
                 quitSprite.setPosition(500, 350);
                menuScene.registerTouchArea(quitSprite);
               menuScene.attachChild(quitSprite);
}
```

Comment: try this one.Start with Andengine examples, So that you get good understanding.All the best.

Comment: How do I run these examples most of these have errors in it asking for all the extensions. Can I run one specific program only without being bothered by those extensions?

Comment: First download all the extentions from  github.Then import all these extentions into eclipse.Next download Andengine examples from github.Now import this into eclipse.Set all extentions as libraries to  this Andengine Example.

Comment: Oh, I really need to download all the extensions then. Thanks Rama.

I really can't make your code function in mine. The sprite just can't be clicked no matter what I do. There are no errors in the code but it still can't be clicked. I really don't know why.

Comment: replace "return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);" with "return true". Try this

Comment: It still won't work. I wonder what's wrong with this code. I've been trying all the ways that I know like transferring the public boolean OnAreaTouched to the GameActivity and inserting the code in the OnPopulateScene yet it still won't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46755/discussion-between-rama-and-user3247200)

Answer (score 1):

I did not got what exactly you want.But you can implement onclick for sprite as follows:

```
ButtonSprite mSoundButton  = new ButtonSprite(30, 30,
                                         ResourceManager.getSoundButtonTR(),
                                         ResourceManager.getEngine().getVertexBufferObjectManager(),
                                         new ButtonSprite.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {


                    }
        });
```

Comment: I'll try this, regarding what I wanted to happen to the code, I want the sprites play and quit to be clickable so that it allows me to play the game or quit it. Thanks Rama

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add click listener to Scene it self you can do as follows:

```
public class MenuScrollerActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements  IClickDetectorListener{
  private ClickDetector mClickDetector;

MenuScrollerActivity(){
this.mClickDetector = new ClickDetector(this);
}

@Override
    public void onClick(ClickDetector arg0, int arg1, float arg2, float arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

 @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
                this.mClickDetector.onTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);

                return true;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do in this way for those functionalities:

```
      Sprite playSprite = new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2, mFruitTiledTextureRegion3, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                            float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                           // you can implement your action
                                      sceneManager.setCurrentScene(AllScenes.GAME);
}

                        return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
                    }
                };

                this.mScene.registerTouchArea(playSprite);
                this.mScene.attachChild(playSprite);
```

Comment: check this code to move from on scene to another on clicking  sprite

Comment: can you explain further how this code is done and what it does? I find it hard to add on my code. where do i place it? In the SceneManager or in the GameActivity?